# AVAudioSession error

Tags: ios, webrtc, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm getting the following error and have no idea what's causing it.

> Aug  4 15:04:56 MyiPad myApp[1523] : 15:04:56.072 ERROR:     [0x78ba000] AVAudioSessionUtilities.h:124: GetProperty_DefaultToZero: AudioSessionGetProperty ('cilt') failed with error: '!siz'

In my app I'm:

- Using AVAudioPlayers to play sounds
- Manipulating the AVAudioSessionCategory and AVAudioSessionMode (changing between SoloAmbient/Default and PlayAndRecord/VideoChat with options: AllowBluetooth | DefaultToSpeaker)
- Using AddLive to make webRTC video calls
- Using the private API [here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/04/23/ios-mirroring-and-programmatic-airplay-selection/) to manipulate AirPlay selection

Obviously there's a lot going on so I don't expect anyone to serve this to me on a platter, but anything you can tell me about the error would be very helpful

**Update 1:** "cilt" stands for [kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareInputLatency](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Property_Identifiers)

**Update 2:** "!siz" means that the size of the property data was not correct (deprecated in iOS 7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed every relevant thread I could find on Google and almost all of them lead to something about the `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers` option. I ORed it with the other options I was using on the PlayAndRecord category and it worked...go figure.

If anyone has any insights into this mystery, please answer or comment, but for now, try that option and see what happens. I'll update when I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this. What I've observed (because of an unrelated issue) is that when a second listener appears I got this error message.  Maybe you are invoking more than one thread that is listening to the audio stream?  Offering this as a (hopefully useful) data point for your consideration.

Comment: Every little piece helps, thanks! I'll look into it.